# change in reputation value in stack overflow relevant in mi yodeya?

Tags: discussion, questions, reputation

In stack overflow they changed the reputation for upvoted question to 10. This applies in mi yodeya?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, it does. This is apparent from [the official SE blog post on the subject](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/11/13/were-rewarding-the-question-askers/) and also from the fact that my MY reputation just jumped quite a bit.

Comment: Ha!  That's one way to get Mi Yodeya to my #2 spot, something I've wanted for a while. :-)

Comment: This is a strange decision. I'm curious to see the reaction of experts in all sites

Comment: @MonicaCellio Now we just need to get your diamonds back and we’ll be in business. How are you doing, by the way?